# Making Community User able to modify his/her profile

Tags: profile, customer-community

I must have done something wrong. The user (customers) of my Community are now unable to modify their profile. How can I make them again able to modify their profile (but not others')?

Comment: Have you looked in your setup history to see what you changed? That might give you a clue on what to do to resolve your issue. For example, have you changed your sharing model for External Users?